# Windows form DataGridView linked to a Dictionary but nothing seen in GUI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a simple windows form with a gridgridview. I am trying to attach a datasource to it. My datasource is a dictionary. When I debug I can see that the values reach the binding source but they are not showing up in the datagrid. I was wondering if anyone could kindly give me an idea as to what is going on.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class DatagridView1GUI : Form
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _d;
    public DatagridView1GUI (Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        const int ROW_HEIGHT = 22;
        InitializeComponent();
        _d = dictionary;

        Height += ROW_HEIGHT * (_d.Count);           
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void DatagridView1GUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _guiDataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ArrayList dataSourceKeys = new ArrayList(_d.Keys);

        foreach (string key in dataSourceKeys)
        {
            _guiDataSource.Add(key, _d[key].State.ToString());
        }

        BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();

        _bindingSource.DataSource = _guiDataSource;
        DatagridView1GUI.DataSource = _bindingSource.DataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: if _d[key] is an object then _d[key].State.ToString() shouldn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the bindingsource to DatagridView1GUI.DataSource. I see that this is your current forms name and not the datagridview to which you want to bind the data.
I believe that your datagridview is dataGridView1.